# trigger useEffect even when a prop remains the same?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to achieve the same results as a regular `useEffect` call, but that is also called whenever one of the *triggers* are reset to the same values?

Here is an example of what I mean

```
const defaultValue = true;
const [state, setState] = useState(defaultValue);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("called");
}, [state]);

setState(defaultValue); // I want this to still trigger the effect (console log)
```

Obviously, I do not want this to be triggered if `setState` is not called. In my case, I also do not have access to `setState` because trigger is passed down as a prop.